# Google Cloud ML Prediction API with Custom Response Structure

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm currently exploring the use of Google Cloud ML to host a model and host a prediction endpoint using the model. One thing I still don't understand is about the response format from the Prediction API itself:

From the [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict), it's written that the response from the API would be in a form of `predictions[]` containing objects with `label` and `scores` field. My questions:

- Is it possible to customize the structure of the objects within `predictions[]`? For example, what if, for a given instance/data, I want the prediction API to return a list of numbers or other possible structure?
- If it's possible, what should I do (e.g., changes in my TensorFlow code? Config files?)?

Until this point, I haven't had a clear picture of how would the Prediction API get what's the form of the response it would give, given my TensorFlow model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining your own outputs is absolutely supported. A typical TensorFlow training program will:

1. Build a training graph
2. Train the model using that graph
3. Build a prediction graph
4. Export a SavedModel

This is exemplified, e.g., in this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/tensorflowcore/trainer/task.py).

When you build your prediction graph, you'll create placeholders for your inputs, something like:

```
with tf.Graph() as prediction_graph:
  # dtypes can be anything
  # First dimension of shape is "batch size" which must be None
  # so the system can send variable-length batches. Beyond that,
  # there are no other restrictions on shape.
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(None,))
  y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,))
  z = build_prediction_graph(x, y)
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

When you're exporting a SavedModel, you declare your inputs and outputs in what's called a "Signature"; in the process you give them friendly names (the keys in the dict), since TensorFlow does name mangling. These keys are what you use in your JSON when sending data and they are the keys in the JSON you get back in prediction.

For example:

```
# Define the inputs and the outputs.
inputs = {"x": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x),
          "y": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y)}
outputs = {"z": tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(z)}
signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
)
```

A hypothetical request to the service using that signature might look like:

```
{"instances": [{"x": 6, "y": 3.14}, {"x": 3, "y": 1.0}]}
```

With a hypothetical response looking like:

```
{"predictions": [{"z": [1, 2, 3]}, {"z": [4, 5, 6]}]}
```

Finally, you will need to actually save out the `SavedModel`:

```
with tf.Session(graph=prediction_graph) as session:
  # Restore the most recently checkpointed variables from training
  saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(job_dir))

  # Save the SavedModel
  b = builder.SavedModelBuilder('/path/to/export')
  b.add_meta_graph_and_variables(session, ['serving_default'], signature)
  b.save()
```